# Property "children" is missing when retrieving synced block

Tags: reactjs, next.js, notion-api

Notion API has supported `synced_block`. I am using the Notion API with Next.js. According to the [docs](https://developers.notion.com/reference/block) and the [changelog](https://developers.notion.com/changelog/synced-block-link-to-page-and-template-block-types-are-now-supported-in-the-api), the output should contain such properties.

> This is an example of an "original" synced_block. Note that all of the blocks available to be synced in another synced_block are captured in the children property.

```
{
    "type": "synced_block",
    "synced_block": {
        "synced_from": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "callout": {
                    "text": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": {
                                "content": "Callout in synced block"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So far, I can get the block_id of the original synced block from the reference synced block.

However, the `children` property is missing for the original synced block. I cannot get the content of the synced_block that I created.

Only the `synced_from` property can be retrieved.

```
"synced_block": {
       "synced_from": null  
}
```

Tried with Postman and get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching for the support from Notion, I found that I misunderstood the API documentation.

Briefly, instead of retrieving a block, I will need another api call to retrieve the block children.

> If you need to retrieve the children of the synced block you can use the "Retrieve block children" endpoint [here in the documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/get-block-children). This will return information on the content inside the synced block.

To retrieve children of a block using `@notionhq/client`:

```js
const response = await notion.blocks.children.list({
    block_id: blockId,
});
```

Comment: Where do you get blockId? I tried using id that comes with block object but didnt work

Comment: @NecmettinSargın It is the synced_block block id. Just make sure you are using the method which is getting its children block